# SSH into Namecheap shared host

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys, sshd

I'm trying to connect to my **Namecheap** shared host server via SSH
I imported the pub/private key and authorized it like so:

[image]

Let's VM IP = `11.11.11.11`

When I SSH, I kept getting

```
➜  Desktop ssh webedcwp@11.11.11.11 -i ~/.ssh/awning -v
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/alpha/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 11.11.11.11 [11.11.11.11] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 11.11.11.11 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 11.11.11.11 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Any hints for me would be great appreciated

Comment: Don't know if your web management interface provides access to the logs, but it would be useful to see what sshd is doing on the other side. And what's in the sshd config file.

Answer (score 0):

Namecheap shared hosting uses nonstandard ports for SSH. To find your port, go to Manage Shell in cPanel. Make sure the "enable SSH access" slider is on. A moment after it's enabled, an Access Details table will appear below, including an "SSH port" row. Supply that port to `ssh` with the `-p` switch, for example:

```
# Replace with your specific port number       ↓↓↓↓↓
ssh username@11.11.11.11 -i ~/.ssh/key_file -p 29999
```

Comment: -p 29999 ??? what.... where do they say that ? wow... let me try that now.

Comment: I tried that and I seems to get similar result. ... hanging.

Comment: 29999 is just a placeholder - you need to look up your specific port in Manage Shell.

Comment: Ah... I missed read your post. Let me see. Thanks man.

Comment: I don't see `manage shell`

Comment: This are all options, I see : https://i.imgur.com/2vJPxJR.jpg

Comment: @code8888 For me it's under "Exclusive for Namecheap Customers" which is collapsed in your screenshot.